# Selecting Element followed by text with Selenium WebDriver

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium WebDriver and the Python bindings to automate some monotonous WordPress tasks, and it has been pretty straightforward up until this point. I am trying to select a checkbox, but the only way that I can identify it is by the text following it. Here is the relevant portion of HTML:

```
<li id="product_cat-52">
    <label class="selectit">
       <input value="52" type="checkbox" name="tax_input[product_cat][]" id="in-product_cat-52"> polishpottery
    </label>
</li>
```

The only information that I have in my script to identify this checkbox is the string "polishpottery". Is there any way to select that checkbox knowing only the text that follows?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @sherwin-wu already said, you should find a way to select what you want based on id or name or class (and most likely a combination of it). In your example there seem to be enough possibilities to do so, although I don't know what the rest of the page normally looks like.

Having that said, it's possible to do what you asked for using an XPath selector like

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li/label/input[contains(..,'polishpottery')]")
```

Comment: It looks like XPath was the answer, I ended up using `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[contains(text(),'polishpottery')]/input")` The reason that I can't select by ID is that I am working with a bunch of pre-entered categories that could have been given any ID, but the only information that I have been given is the category name. Thank you for the answer - it was just what I needed!

Comment: Great, it's almost equivalent. So use whatever you find more readable!

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions -- probably not the best solution, but it should work.

```
import re

def get_id(str, html_page): # str in this case would be 'polishpottery'
    return re.search(r'<input[^<>]*?type="checkbox"[^<>]*?id="([A-Za-z0-9_ -]*?)"[^<>]*?> ?' + str, html_page).group(1)

id = get_id('polishpottery', html)
checkbox = driver.find_element_by_id(id)
checkbox.toggle()

# Or, more minimallistically:
driver.find_element_by_id(get_id('polishpottery', html)).toggle()
```

Output:

```
>>> print(html)
<li id="product_cat-52">
    <label class="selectit">
       <input value="52" type="checkbox" name="tax_input[product_cat][]" id="in-product_cat-52"> polishpottery
    </label>
</li>
>>> get_id('polishpottery', html)
'in-product_cat-52'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend trying to find more ways to select the checkbox. For example, you could select the li tag based on its id using browser.find_element_by_id(id). You could also select based on the name using browser.find_element_by_name(name).

Alternatively, if you really can't, you can select for the text using selenium + BeautifulSoup.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source)
text = soup.find('input', re.compile=" polishpottery")
checkbox = text.parent 
# it might not exactly be parent, but you can play around with
# navigating the tree.
```

Hope this helps!