# How to select checkbox by passing the checkbox name - using Selenium / Webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

HTML source page:

//start:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_control1_pnlEdit">

     <h2>
        <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_control1_lblEditHeader">Add New</span></h2>
    <br /><br />


    <div>
        <table class="DetailsView" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" rules="all" border="1" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_control1" style="height:50px;width:600px;border-collapse:collapse;">
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td><td>              
                    &nbsp;</td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>Category</td><td>  
                    <div style="border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; border-color: inherit; overflow:auto; height:200px; width:300px;" >
                        <table id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_control1_lstCat" class="CheckBoxList" selectionmode="Multiple" border="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td><span style="padding-left:0px;"><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_control1_lstCat_0" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$control1$dv$lstCat$0" /><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_control1_lstCat_0">Item 
                            1</label></span></td>
                    </tr><tr>
                        <td><span style="padding-left:15px;"><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_control1_lstCat_1" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$control1$dv$lstCat$1" />Item 
                            1-2</span></td>
                    </tr><tr>
                        <td><span style="padding-left:15px;"><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_control1_lstCat_2" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$control1$dv$lstCat$2" /><span>Item 
                            1-3</span></span></td>
                    </tr><tr>
                        <td><span style="padding-left:15px;"><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_control1_lstCat_3" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$control1$dv$lstCat$3" /><span>Item 
                            1-4</span></span></td>
                    </tr><tr>
                        <td><span style="padding-left:0px;"><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_control1_lstCat_4" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$control1$dv$lstCat$4" /><span>Item 
                            2</span></span></td>
                    </tr><tr>
                        <td><span style="padding-left:15px;"><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_control1_lstCat_5" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$control1$dv$lstCat$5" /><span>Item 
                            2-1</span></span></td>
                    </tr><tr>
                        <td><span style="padding-left:0px;"><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_control1_lstCat_6" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$control1$dv$lstCat$6" /><span>Item 
                            3</span></span></td>
                    </tr><tr>
                        <td><span style="padding-left:15px;"><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_control1_lstCat_7" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$control1$dv$lstCat$7" /><span>Item 
                            3-1</span></span></td>
                    </tr>

                </table>     

                    </div>                                                   
                </td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>    

</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

//end

**EDIT:** [Selecting Element followed by text with Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11406091/selecting-element-followed-by-text-with-selenium-webdriver/11409449#11409449)

my question is similar to the above post

**END EDIT**

Below is my page source code it renders at runtime

i have unique checkbox id that generates for each checkbox for an example:

```
ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Control1_stCat_1
ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Control1_stCat_2
ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Control1_stCat_3
..........................................
ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Control1_stCat_8
etc..............
```

My requirement is: if I pass the `Checkbox Text` then it should Select the related checkbox
for an example:

if I pass the Checkbox Text = `Some text present.....` then Checkbox Id `ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Control1_stCat_1` should be checked

PS: `Item 1, Item 2` is just an example in the real data I have some random names

Below is my html code generate:

```
<tr>
<td>Category</td>
<td>
<div style="border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; border-color: inherit; overflow:auto; height:200px; width:300px;">
<table id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_AddControl1_lstCat" class="CheckBoxList" border="0" selectionmode="Multiple">
<tbody>
<tr> 
  <td>
    <span style="padding-left:15px;">
    <input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Control1_stCat_1" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$AddControl1$cat$lstCat$1"/>
    <label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_AddControl1_lstCat_8">Item 1</label>
    </span>
 </td>
</tr>

<tr> 
  <td>
    <span style="padding-left:15px;">
    <input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Control1_stCat_2" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$AddControl1$cat$lstCat$2"/>
    <label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_AddControl1_lstCat_2">Item 2</label>
    </span>
  </td>
</tr>

<tr> 
  <td>
    <span style="padding-left:15px;">
    <input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Control1_stCat_3" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$AddControl1$cat$lstCat$3"/>
    <label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_AddControl1_lstCat_3">Item 3</label>
    </span>
  </td>
</tr>

.............
..............
................
.................
more...............
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int i=1;

while(!driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Control1_stCat_"+i)).equals(null)){

    if(driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Control1_stCat_"+i)).getText()="Item1"){

        driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Control1_stCat_"+i)).click();
        break;

        }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can use a lil bit another approach.

```
String  cssSelectorChckbox1= "table[id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_AddControl1_lstCat']" tbody tr td>input[id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Control1_stCat_1']";
String cssSelectorChckboxLabel1="table[id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_AddControl1_lstCat']" tbody tr td>label[for='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_AddControl1_lstCat_8']";

//then you can use 2 js methods: one for click checkbox, second one for validation label text near chckbox:

public void  clickOnTheElement(String cssLocator){
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append("var x = $(\'"+cssLocator+"\');");
        stringBuilder.append("x.click();");
        js.executeScript(stringBuilder.toString());

}

public String getTextOfTheElement(String cssLocator)
{ JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

stringBuilder.append("var x = $(\""+cssLocator+"\");");
        stringBuilder.append("return x.text().toString();")       ;


       String res= (String) js.executeScript(stringBuilder.toString());
       return res;
}

//using first method you are able to click on checkbox. 

clickOnTheElement( cssSelectorChckbox1);
//using second method you are able to verify that label near checkbox is correct:
String actualCheckboxLabel=getTextOfTheElement(cssSelectorChckboxLabel1);
Assert.assertTrue(actualCheckboxLabel.equals("expected text near checkbox"))
```

Hope this somehow helps you)

Answer (score 0):

You could use an XPath expression like:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[normalize-space(../label) = 'Item 1']")
```

Comment: seems like the way to go but tried with the above line but did not work complaining about `Unable to find element with xpath == //input[contains(../label,'Item 1')]`  `driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[contains(../label,'Item 1')]")).Click();`

Comment: I do not have your full page nor do I know which driver you use. What does work however is: Copy from your pasted html everything from the opening `table` tag to the last closing `tr` tag, paste it to a file and add a closing table tag and save as some html file. This way the XPath works with a combination of Firefox/Firebug/FirePath. I strongly suspect it will work in a Testcase as well. (The problem lies in incorrectly cascaded html or something else we cannot see in your question).

Comment: @AbuHamzah: There is an html code extract, but not your complete page and also nothing complete for testing. As it is, it is not valid. To test with it I have to guess what you meant and add tags (like an opening table, a closing div, two closing tables)

Comment: You have lots of additional whitespace between 'Item' and the number, so 'Item 1' cannot match. If you search for just 'Item' it finds the box labelled 'Item 1'. (No further matches because it is the only box with a `label`). If you have control over the code generation consider adapting that. If not you might wannt to use XPath's `matches` with a search pattern.

Comment: its typo on my end... how do you do xpath's matches? and i tried trim out but does not match the item.... ergggggggggggg

Comment: When I past my code the format messed up but I don't see any white space in my page. So how the xpath will be looks like for the above HTML code I posted?

Comment: The white space in the html source (not shown like that in the browser is a line break and spaces for indention, between 'Item' and '1'. Anyway, got a better idea and adjusted my answer.

Comment: Did not work, I think I am not using correct xpath that may be the problem... Based on the above HTML would you tell me what should I include iny path? I am using ff and try to get the xpath but no avail.